# Calculating thermistor value to replace fixed resistor

Tags: thermistor, inrush-current

I have a circuit that uses a 5W 100Ω fixed resistor for inrush limiting. I'd like to replace it with a thermistor for better efficiency. I've not found any information referencing what resistance to use. Can anyone suggest a resistance value or a formula I can use to do the calculation?

Comment: Measure the voltage drop over the resistor to see how much current is passing through, then see if you can replace it with the same value NTC thermistor or maybe bypass it with a relay.

Comment: @electronsurf may be PTC resistor?